# How to solve CORS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing error in angular 6

Tags: angular

I have seperately restfull webservice.
I use angular 6 in my front-end project. 
When I post data using httpClient I get an error like this

```
    error => cors header 'access-control-allow-origin' missing
```

here is my Angular code:

```
     login(username:string , password:string){
        var param = "username=" +username + "&password=" + password ;
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/login",param);
       }
```

Comment: You need to set it up in both api and UI. I am not sure which framework you are using for your REST api. But there is a process to allow cross origin requests in each framework. Then you need to add the below header in your POST api call . `let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('access-control-allow-origin',"http://localhost:8080/"); ` and pass that header to the http POST call.

Comment: There is also a section about this in the Angular docs here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#requesting-services-from-a-different-server-cors

Comment: which back end technology are you using ??